# Teamup cURL & CF7 submit

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I need some help. I have a CF7 form and on submit I would like that can be executed this curl command (it is a Team up post / new event)

```
 curl "https://api.teamup.com/my-cal-id/events" -XPOST -H 'Teamup-Token: "my-token"' -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data '{"subcalendar_id": 2306154,"start_dt": "2017-03-23T08:00:00-0400","end_dt": "2017-03-23T09:00:00-0400","all_day": false,"rrule": "","title": "RAGIONE SOCIALE","who": "OPERATOR","location": "location-sample","notes": "NOTES"}'
```

Now, i have these problems:

1. How can i auto execute this curl from cf7?
2. subcalendar-id must be generated from another list of params, for
   example: in the form decoded "agent n.1" must be coded in "3374384"
3. location must be the result of 3 different fields, for example: address+city+province from the form's ids
4. start-dt is coded i don't know what and i'd like that, if i write on the form 10/10/017 and 10.00 these fields can be coded together in 2017-10-10T10:00:00-0400"

I'm not so experienced guys, so sorry and thanks for your kind help

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with the command line when you're using Wordpress? https://secure.php.net/curl

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.. you mean something like this?

<?php

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Teamup-Token' => 'API_KEY']]);
$result = $client->post('https://api.teamup.com/ks73ad7816e7a61b3a/events', [
    'json' => [
        "subcalendar_id" => 730624,
        "start_dt" => "2015-06-17T06:00:00-0400",
        "end_dt" => "2015-06-17T07:00:00-0400",
        "all_day" => false,
        "rrule" => "",
        "title" => "Demo Event",
        "who" => "",
        "location" => "",
        "notes" => "",
    ]
]);

Comment: Yeah. Technically, Guzzle is a library, but it uses curl and makes it easier to use.